# Pipe Image Stream into Identify Command

Tags: imagemagick

I'm trying to find the unique amount of colors in an image and I've come across ImageMagick's identify tool that is used at the command line.

```
identify -unique-colors sunset.png
```

This has worked well in my tests, giving me much more accurate results compared to other tools.

My problem is the images I'd like to incorporate this into a script to examine images that aren't written to the hard drive. Is it possible to pipe a stream of data into the command? Something like:

```
echo xxx | identify -unique-colors
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"a stream of data"*? Do you mean a PNG-encoded image? A JPEG-encoded image? Raw RGB pixels? Raw greyscale pixels? 8-bit? 16-bit? What OS are you using? What language are you calling this from? It doesn't seem very efficient.

Comment: I'm using PHP but the built in image tools to detect number of colors in an image is incorrect. The images I need to analyze are in database files as the images are numerous and small making for a database to be the most efficient method to store them versus them each taking their own inode. I query the database and have the image's binary data to work with. I'm trying to avoid excessive hard drive writes by temporarily writing this image to disk to identify the color count. I'm using Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I have understood your use case. Effectively, you want to do this with PHP:

```
cat IMAGE.PNG | magick - -unique-colors txt:
```

or

```
cat IMAGE.JPG | magick - -unique-colors txt:
```

The `-` tells **ImageMagick** to read from its `stdin`.